# using raw query in where methods makes error in query generation

Tags: laravel-5

I have an eloquent query as

```
Role::where("(company_id = Auth::user()->company_id or name = 'admin')and id in(2,3)")->pluck('name');
```

According to my eloquent the sql should be as

```
select `name` from `roles` where ( company_id = 1 or name = admin ) and id IN (2, 3) and `roles`.`deleted_at` is null
```

But it executes as

```
select `name` from `roles` where ( company_id = 1 or name = admin ) and id IN (2, 3) is null and `roles`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Can anyone help me concluding why extra `is null` condition is applied in the query?

Note: I am using soft deletes

Comment: please format your question. It is very confusing

Comment: What's your actual PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use whereRaw instead of where

```
Role::whereRaw("(company_id = Auth::user()->company_id or name = 'admin')and id in(2,3)")->pluck('name');
```